# Is there a way to access an intranet web application over internet

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, intranet

I would like to know if there is any possibility of accessing an Intranet web application over internet. By this i mean complete access of the application including the database used for the web application.

If there is a way to access.Please anyone let me know the procedure

Thanks

Comment: I think you are thinking about VPN.

Comment: VPN is the most obvious acronym that springs to mind

Answer (score 0):

VPN is the good way to do this.

The process greatly depends on your internal network structure.
And one has to set up a way-in first.

Check out OpenVPN
http://openvpn.net/

Comment: thanks for your reply.. through VPN can i have access to a stand alone application on an intranet??

Comment: if you install some remote access software on your machine in the office, the yes. like **ssh** for servers, or **vnc** for desktops. What VPN does, is makes your home computer, as if it was next to your office computer on the company network.

Comment: By using VNC can i have access to an application build using VB(Visual Basic) on a clients system?

Comment: using VNC you have access to your screen,keyboard and mouse. So basically you can do almost everything you can do, sitting in front of that computer. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing

Comment: Yes, but a bit older,dumber and not requiring you to use an external service. Which is good for security. Even as VNC is far from being secure itself, but the VPN takes care of that.